# Lua standalone with external binary program

Tags: linux, executable, lua

I am writing a small program to us in LuaLaTex. The purpose of it is to produce an qr-code with a given uuid, the qr-code is printed on the page and the uuid is stored in the pdf's meta-data.

Nevertheless I thought it would be nice to have a single executable in the `texmf` folder to called by the class file from my document. To generate the qr-codes i used (Linux) `qrencode & convert` with this lua script `uuidqrcode.lua`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env lua 

function gen_qr_uuid ()
    local uuid = require 'uuid'
    -- uuid.seed(math.randomseed(os.time()))
    local encode = uuid()
    local name = encode
    local format = 'pdf'

    local qrencode = string.format(
        [[qrencode \
            --type=EPS \
            --output=%s.eps \
            --size=10 \
            --level=H \
            --margin=0 \
            --casesensitive \
            %s \
            ]], 
            name,
            encode)

    local convert = string.format(
        [[convert \
            %s.eps \
            %s.%s \
            ]],
            name,
            name,
            format)

    local rmeps = string.format("rm %s.eps", name)

    os.execute(qrencode)
    os.execute(convert)
    os.execute(rmeps)
end

for i=1, (arg[1] or 1) do
    gen_qr_uuid ()
end
```

To convert this script to a standalone executable i used `luastatic` with this script `makeluaexec`:

```
#!/bin/sh
luastatic $1 `pkg-config --libs --cflags lua`
```

With this I have a single executable file but it sill depends on `qrencode & convert`, so when I move to a other Linux machine these tools has to be installed. Is there a way to pack these tools into my self generated executable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The `qrencode` program is just a wrapper around [libqrencode](https://github.com/fukuchi/libqrencode), and the `convert` command is just a wrapper around [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php). Instead of calling those commands, call the library functions from your code directly. Bindings such as https://github.com/isage/lua-imagick and https://github.com/vincascm/qrencode will be useful for this. Then, when you call `luastatic`, just pass in the relevant static libraries.

Comment: Hi Joseph,
thank you for the hint to these library's, after a little wiggle to install the `lua-imagick` on my centos machine (ImageMagick has to be a newer version, but they provide rpm's, so was not that big deal), I noticed that the lua library / binding of `qrencode` only provides suport for "ASCII and PNG" so there is no need anymore for the `convert` command. So i do not get the desired qr-code in pdf (vector) format. 

Basically I can work with the solution now, but back to my first question, is it possible to include a executable?

Comment: Not without a lot of trouble. It would be much easier to modify the qrencode bindings (or write new ones) so they support EPS.

Comment: I found this [Embedding binary data in executables](https://csl.name/post/embedding-binary-data/), maybe this works for this use case? I mean on [lua-imagick](https://github.com/isage/lua-imagick) they say: "FFI-based bindings are hackish and buggy" but are very convenient and already well documented. What do you think about this approach? Could it be done with writing a auxlib?

Comment: You could, but then you'd have to extract it from the binary into a temporary file to run it, then delete it when it's done, and you'd have to get/build statically-linked versions of the programs, or they'd fail due to missing dependencies.

Comment: Ok, I think this approach with binding these things into the executable is not the best way to go, better write a function which checks if the dependencies are available and if not exiting the program before running in a error.
Thanks a lot for your help